# How to speed up TF model training? MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy looks a lot slower than non-distributed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, distributed-training

Using the code in the [Keras distributed training example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras); using TF 2.4.1.

Following other docs:

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training#multiworkermirroredstrategy

On a single m5.large node in AWS training with the MNIST model takes 1m 47s. With 3 machines of that type and MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy in place, it takes 4 mins 30 seconds.

Is it just because the training is on a 'relatively small' MNIST model and it starts to truly shine on large or very large datasets?

My actual input data is much larger. What is the best approach for model training on 1/2 GB of data? 1 GB? 2 GB? Non-distributed on a single node is a non-starter but the MNIST run on MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy raises speed concerns.

The MNIST based test code is below.

Non-distributed:

```
import json
import os
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
if "." not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, ".")


def mnist_dataset(batch_size):
    (x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    # The `x` arrays are in uint8 and have values in the range [0, 255].
    # You need to convert them to float32 with values in the range [0, 1]
    x_train = x_train / np.float32(255)
    y_train = y_train.astype(np.int64)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).shuffle(60000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return train_dataset


def build_and_compile_cnn_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28)),
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        ]
    )
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    return model


start_time = time.time()

global_batch_size = 64
multi_worker_dataset = mnist_dataset(global_batch_size)

multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_cnn_model()

multi_worker_model.fit(multi_worker_dataset, epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=70)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
str_elapsed_time = time.strftime("%H : %M : %S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))

print(">> Finished. Time elapsed: {}.".format(str_elapsed_time))
```

Distributed:

```
import json
import os
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "-1"
if "." not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(0, ".")


def mnist_dataset(batch_size):
    (x_train, y_train), _ = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
    # The `x` arrays are in uint8 and have values in the range [0, 255].
    # You need to convert them to float32 with values in the range [0, 1]
    x_train = x_train / np.float32(255)
    y_train = y_train.astype(np.int64)
    train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).shuffle(60000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return train_dataset


def build_and_compile_cnn_model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28)),
            tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(28, 28, 1)),
            tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        ]
    )
    model.compile(
        loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.001),
        metrics=["accuracy"],
    )
    return model


start_time = time.time()

per_worker_batch_size = 64
tf_config = json.loads(os.environ["TF_CONFIG"])
num_workers = len(tf_config["cluster"]["worker"])

strategy = tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy()

# global_batch_size = per_worker_batch_size * num_workers
# multi_worker_dataset = mnist_dataset(global_batch_size)

# OR - turn on sharding
global_batch_size = 64
options = tf.data.Options()
options.experimental_distribute.auto_shard_policy = tf.data.experimental.AutoShardPolicy.DATA
multi_worker_dataset = mnist_dataset(global_batch_size)
multi_worker_dataset_with_shrd = multi_worker_dataset.with_options(options)

with strategy.scope():
    # Model building/compiling need to be within `strategy.scope()`.
    multi_worker_model = build_and_compile_cnn_model()

multi_worker_model.fit(multi_worker_dataset_with_shrd, epochs=50, steps_per_epoch=70)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
str_elapsed_time = time.strftime("%H : %M : %S", time.gmtime(elapsed_time))

print(">> Finished. Time elapsed: {}.".format(str_elapsed_time))
```